# Undefined property: PDO::$affected_rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

after editing my old code to new i get error `Undefined property: PDO::$affected_rows` and here is the part `if ($this->dbCon->affected_rows > 0)`  can some one help me to solve this problem

```
class Relation {

private $loggedInUser;
private $dbCon;
public function getRelationship(User $user) {
        $user_one = (int) $this->loggedInUser->getUserId();
        $user_two = (int) $user->getUserId();
        if ($user_one > $user_two) {
            $temp = $user_one;
            $user_one = $user_two;
            $user_two = $temp;
        }
        $resultObj = $this->dbCon->prepare('SELECT * FROM relationship WHERE user_one_id=:user_one AND user_two_id=:user_two');
        $resultObj->execute(array(':user_one' => $user_one,':user_two' => $user_two));
        if ($this->dbCon->affected_rows > 0) {
            $row = $resultObj->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $relationship = new Relationship();
            $relationship->arrToRelationship($row, $this->dbCon);
            return $relationship;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

}}

Comment: In pdo we use [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to check the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement

Comment: @Saty tried i get this `Call to undefined method PDO::rowCount() `

Comment: Show us how you use `rowCount()`

Comment: You can also use `$resultObj->fetchColumn() > 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A PDO object has no `affected_rows` property. Instead you can call [`rowCount()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) on the PDOStatement:

```
if ($resultObj->rowCount() > 0) {
```

Side note: not all databases support the `rowCount()` method for SELECT queries, but MySQL does.

Comment: tried i get this `Call to undefined method PDO::rowCount() `

Comment: Look carefully, my code calls it on the `$resultObj` not `$this->dbCon`.

Comment: then what about dbcon